# My camera jerks while following the car gameobject. Is there a way to fix my camera follow script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game in which the camera follows a car. The code is following the car but it shows jerkiness in the whole environment.

```
void LateUpdate()     
{     
    Vector3 lookOnObject = Player.position - transform.position;     
    transform.forward = lookOnObject.normalized;     
    Vector3 playerLastPosition;     
    playerLastPosition = Player.position - lookOnObject.normalized * distanceFromObject;     
     playerLastPosition.y = Player.position.y + distanceFromObject / 2;
     transform.position = playerLastPosition;     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Vector3.SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html) for smooth camera movement and to remove jitter.

---

First, add the following fields:

```cs
private Vector3 currentVelocity;
private float smoothTime;
```

Then replace the last line in the `LateUpdate` with this:

```cs
transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, playerLastPosition, ref currentVelocity, smoothTime);
```